# How to integrate messages from Slackbot on the site?

Tags: php, html, slack-api

There is an account on the slackbot. There is a bot that sends me data every 2 minutes, in the form of text and links, after receiving this data, I need to display them on the site. Website on Html + PHP how to do this mind I will not put it. I know that somehow through Api is done, but I do not guess. Can anyone have examples? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but Stackoverflow is not about teaching you basic programming skills and its not a coding service. If you like to learn more about how to display messages on a website, check out his this great website teaching PHP basics: https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Just follow one of these top tutorials: https://api.slack.com/tutorials

Also take a good look into the api documentation:
https://api.slack.com/

Comment: It can be easy for You. For me it's a problem. Sorry if I distracted you.